# Can I create a tape backup that uses Microsoft Tape Format (MTF) on Linux?

Tags: linux, backup, tar, tape

Outside of [LTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_Tape_File_System), the [Microsoft Tape Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Tape_Format) seems to be the closest to a widely supported format when it comes to older tape format that don't support LTFS (In my case, Ultrium 3 and 4).

However, while there are [several ways to read MTF tapes on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213162/restoring-from-ntbackup-tape), it seems that nothing creates tapes using it - opting instead of raw use of tar(/cpio/pax) and mt, or "bigger" backup solutions like Bacula/BareOS.

Is my understanding correct that tar really only covers one "archive" on a tape, while MTF is meant to cover the tape as a whole? And if yes, is there a utility on Linux that uses MTF as a tape backup format?

Comment: Drawing a blank. You may need to dig deeper by checking lists of backup apps such as https://curlie.org/Computers/Software/Backup and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_backup_software

Comment: The tar format is standardized, while the Microsoft format is not. I recommend to use tar because it is standard.

Answer (score 0):

Tar provides a method to append to the existing archive.  Tar is based on standards.  I can open a tar from an old Unix (SCO Openserver or Xenix) the same as one created under Mac OS or Linux.
Here is the link to appending using tar: [https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/appending-files.html#:~:text=The%20simplest%20way%20to%20add,as%20there%20is%20no%20default](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/appending-files.html#:%7E:text=The%20simplest%20way%20to%20add,as%20there%20is%20no%20default).

Comment: I don’t see how this even comes close to beginning to answer the question.   And, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/414534)